# How can i make an basic GUI application in PostScript

Tags: user-interface, imagemagick, ghostscript, interpreter, postscript

I have searched in google regards the GUI application for postscript. I was redirected to this page https://www.whoishostingthis.com/resources/postscript/

And got some tools name which is mentioned below:

1)ImageMagick-(Installed successfully,But not working)
2)Pslib- Library
3)Gnuplot- A command-line graphics and data visualization tool
4)Cairo- Library
5)GNUEnscript-Tool which is used to convert ASCII files into PostScript files
6)GNU a2ps- Any to PostScript filter

Please Guide me from here,To make an GUI application in PostScript

Thanks in advance..

Comment: What do you mean 'a GUI application in PostScript' ? While PostScript is a programming language it has limited scope for interacting with the operating system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few options and a lot of caveats. As Ken rightly says, PostScript has a limited scope for interacting with the operating system. There are a few technologies that extended the basic PostScript environment for GUI applications, namely NeWS (from Sun) and Display PostScript (from Adobe). While these worked somewhat differently, PostScript was primarily intended to be an output-only component of a larger application using the C API.

Some options for a similar kind of setup would be running ToastScript as part of a larger Java application. Or maybe scripting ghostscript with TCL or Python.

Without a lot of extra work, you can use ghostscript for graphical output as long as the input comes from the terminal. Eg. [my Mandelbrot  Set program](http://web.archive.org/web/20160404161534/https://code.google.com/p/xpost/downloads/detail?name=mandel2.ps&can=2&q=).